# Applications of Banach space homology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, homological-algebra, soft-question, banach-spaces

There is a well-developed theory of Banach space homology. What are some of its useful applications to Banach space theory and which important questions can one answer using it? In other words, how would you convince someone to study the theory of Banach space homology?